# Gradle: change is springboot version causes error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, compiler-errors, versioning

Have the following gradle, (basic one generated form start.spring.io). This compiles fine.

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.svadhyayanetworks'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But as soon i change from version '2.2.6.RELEASE' to '2.3.0.M4'. The build errors out as below.
Lot of solutions pointed out the *repositories* which imo seems correct.
Help is greatly appreciated.
My expectation was gradle removes the jars of older version and downloads fresh.

````
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.0.M4'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.3.0.M4')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `settings.gradle` with the following:

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}
```

By default Gradle only looks at the official Gradle Maven repository. Spring publishes milestones/prereleases to their own repository.